# how to select database value based on most common field using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def selected
    @enquiries = Enquiry.all 
    @enquiry_details = EnquiryDetail.all
    @comments = Comment.all
    @enquiries.where("created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day, Time.zone.now.end_of_day)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @enquiries and @enquiry_details and @comments  }
    end  
  end
```

How to call this method in my view.

```
<%= link_to '<button type="button">SELECT</button>'.html_safe, method: :selected %>
```

Comment: what's your question? Be more precise

Comment: Can you explain what you need? or What you are trying to do?

Comment: It didn't help much either.Still its unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: select values from database where created_at is today date

Comment: For that you just has to give like this `@some_variable = @enquiries.where("created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day, Time.zone.now.end_of_day)`

Comment: created_at field type is timestamp, how i can select today created value from database and how to call this method in my view

Comment: hi pavan this is not working, it will throw "undefined method `where' for #<Array:0x9dac6f0>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a route for the action **`selected`** and then do this;

```
<%= button_to "SELECT", { :controller => "CONTROLLER", :action => "selected"} %>
```